# How to implement an algorithm to solve this following homework in O(n) time by suffix tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bioinformatics, string-matching, suffix-array

I have a question in bioinformatics. You can solve it by suffix tree structure.

Given a string S=S[1…n] and a number k, we want to find the smallest sub-string of S that occurs in S exactly k times, if it exists. How to solve this problem in O(n) time?

Answer (score 1):

Build the suffix tree of the string O(N).

Count for every node the number of leafs under it O(N).

Find a node where the `count == k`. The path from the root to that node is a substring that repeats exactly k times.